# Linker path in Visual Studio

Tags: path, linker

## I don't know how to make a linker path that works on multiple computers

(in linker path I mean the path in *project properties -> Configuration manager -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories*)

*running visual studio 2022, windows 11

- I've made a project and although I can access the .libs' folder, once I try it on another computer it doesn't work because the **path from C: to the folder is different**
- the folders look like this:

```
├─ 'myProject'
│         ├─- 'mySolution' with .vsxproj and .sln
│         ├─- 'OpenSSL'
│                  └─ ...
│                        └─ 'Lib' with .lib
```

even an entry about it in the MSDN would be helpful

I tried with relative path but it didn't work...